# PHP gmp_perfect_square doesn't work

Tags: php

I need to check whether a number is a perfect square, I found this function `gmp_perfect_square` in the manual, but it gives me that error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function gmp_perfect_square()`

Answer (score 3):

Does your server has the GMP extension enabled/installed? Because i believe you don't.

What phpinfo() has to say about that?
(http://www.php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php)

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't exist in the version of PHP you have installed. You can either install an extension which adds this function, or implement your own perfect square function.